# NodeJS Forever Não para

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tenho um servidor ubuntu, e usei o comando `forever restart` mas esqueci que não havia instalado um node-module, ou seja, quando fiz o comando `forever list` apareceu ele stopped, ai usei o comando `forever start server.js` e ficou 2 registros no `forever list` com a situação stopped, pois bem, instalei o node-module que faltava e usei o comando `forever start server.js`, no fim das contas, deu certo, mas agora fiz um `forever restart server.js` e ele iniciou os 3, como eu excluo eles? ou paro? atualmente parece que está os 3 rodando.

Answer (score 1):

O `forever` tem um comando que mata todas as sessões ativas no momento.

Basta executar `forever stopall`.
Depois disso inicie apenas o processo correto.

Referência: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever#usage

Você pode finalizar um processo específico usando o `forever stop ID`. Nesse caso basta identificar o processo pelo `ID` ou até mesmo pelo índice dele na lista.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o seguinte comando para matar os processos no linux com determinado nome:

```
pkill 'forever'
```

Depois inicie apenas o processo que deseja novamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode limpar os logs, depois de dar `forever stop "id"` execute o `forever cleanlogs`.

Ele não irá mais aparecer